# Defining set of $\omega$ in probability space $\Omega$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Consider the sum of random variables $S_n:=X_1+...+X_n$ with $X_k \in \mathbb{N}_0$.

I want to definie the set of $\omega$ for that  $S_n(\omega)$ takes different values.

My approach:

$$\Omega:=\{ \omega \in \Omega, n \in \mathbb{N}: \omega=(\omega_1,...,\omega_n)\}.$$

Can I do that in such way?

Comment: @Surb: I thought so :(. If you consider the set $\{S_n=k\}$. There are$ \omega \in \Omega$ such that $S_n(\omega)=k$

Comment: How can I define the set of all these $\omega$